# How to delay initializing a member variable

Tags: c++

I have class defined like so:

```
class GlslProgram
{
public:
    class Format {
    public:
        Format& vertex(const char* shader_path);
        std::string m_vertex_shader;

    private:
        std::string load_shader(const char* shader_path);
    };

    void use() const;
    void uniform(const GLchar* name, const GLboolean value) const;


    GlslProgram() {};
    GlslProgram(const Format& format, const bool separable = false);

private:
    GLuint m_handle;
    GLuint compile_shader(const std::string shader_string, const GLenum 
};
```

The second constructor (i.e. `GlslProgram(const Format& format, const bool separable = false);` is the only one I want to use or have be available.

I want to delete the default constructor (or make it private) however I can't because I have to declare (uninitialized) instances of `GlslProgram` as members of another class in my application.

i.e.

```
class BasicCubeExample : public Application
{
private:
    virtual void set_info()
    {
        Application::set_info();    
        m_info.title = "Basic cube example";
    }
    // Here the format is not yet known so I can not call the correct constructor (at this time)
    GlslProgram m_shader;
};
```

So, by declaring `GlslProgram m_shader;` I both call the default constructor of `GlslProgram` (which I do not want to do) and I have to keep the default constructor available (which I do no want to do).

How can I declare an instance of a class as a member variable without calling its default constructor?

Comment: Can you make `m_shader` a pointer?

Comment: Yes. Would that solve this issue?

Comment: @Startec If it is a pointer, just don't allocate at construction

Comment: Yes, if you make it a pointer you can call its constructor at a later stage by using the `new` operator.

Comment: Even better: Make it a smart pointer such as `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Why cant you use a pointer, intialized to NULL and then assign an object using new when you are ready? Is it that you cant change BasicCubeExample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution (mentioned in comments and another answer) is to allocate the program in `BasicCubeExample` dynamically and hold it by a smart pointer.

There is also an alternative which avoids dynamic allocation, namely [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (or, before C++17, [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)):

```
class BasicCubeExample : public Application
{
private:
    virtual void set_info()
    {
        Application::set_info();    
        m_info.title = "Basic cube example";
    }
    // Here the format is not yet known so I can not call the correct constructor (at this time)
    std::optional<GlslProgram> m_shader;
};
```

Later, initialise it like this:

```
m_shader.emplace(format, separable);
```

In usage afterwards, `optional` is dereferenced just like a pointer, using `*m_shader` or `m_shader->something`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the member `m_shader` as a pointer so that it can be initialized at a later stage.

```
class BasicCubeExample : public Application
{
private:
    virtual void set_info()
    {
        Application::set_info();    
        m_info.title = "Basic cube example";
    }
    // Here the format is not yet known so I can not call the correct constructor (at this time)
    GlslProgram* m_shader;
};
```

Initialize at a later stage like this:

```
m_shader = new GlslProgram(.... arguments);
```

You will have to de-allocate the memory in the destructor of `BasicCubeExample` class as follows.

```
BasicCubeExample::~BasicCubeExample()
{
    delete m_shader;
}
```

An even better alternative would be to use smart pointers so you don't have to worry about de-allocation. Declare `m_shader` as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<GlslProgram> m_shader;
```

Comment: 6+ years after C++11, owning raw pointers shouldn't be suggested at all unless the situation is explicitly described as so limited smart pointers are not usable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call the correct constructor in the initializer list:

```
BasicCubeExample() : m_shader(GlslProgram(format, separable)) {};
```